# how can fix visual studio installation error in vs code and android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, visual-studio-code, error-handling

[image: this type of error show in my pc]

required to solve this error quickly.

Comment: Could you please let us know of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ and download the Community edition.
During the installation you have to install the package "Desktop development with C++", which should be in the category "Windows"
If you installed everything flutter should work

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am satisfied with your answer.